# How reliable are relay modules?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, relay, motor-controller, solid-state-relay

I would like to ask how reliable are these relay modules. Is it possible to use them in industrial application that will run non-stop for months? If not, what alternatives can I use?

[mechanical relay](https://www.reichelt.de/entwicklerboards-relais-modul-4-channel-5-v-srd-05vdc-sl-c-debo-relais-4ch-p242811.html?PROVID=2788&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIjpPI9oW38AIVZbR3Ch3ZPgkvEAQYAyABEgJHffD_BwE)

[solid state relay](https://www.roboter-bausatz.de/detail/index/sArticle/1165?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5OmT_oW38AIVh6Z3Ch0vQQx_EAQYBSABEgIvRvD_BwE)

Comment: If you are looking for serious reliability in a small module then look for hybrid relays that use a combination of a mechanical relay along with a solid state relay. Those will run a very long time, if well designed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are relays reliable for long time use?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/167692/are-relays-reliable-for-long-time-use)

Comment: Download the specs and look to see how many cycles are in the mean "time" till failure or mean cycles until failure. I would think solid state will last longer.  See if there is more quiescent current or leakage with the solid state. With info on these considerations you can decide.

Comment: Some relays are sold with a data sheet that details the expected time to failure versus different breaking currents and load inductance. Some are not. Have a guess which are likely to be more reliable. Generally we say 'no data sheet, no deal'.

Answer (score 3):

Any module's reliability depends on the quality of the parts and the quality of the assembly and the quality of the design.

Cheap parts with wide tolerances put together without much thought into the design and assembled sloppily for pennies to make pennies by an unknown manufacturer and then shipped in questionable conditions will undoubtedly have a higher fail rate than a module made from quality parts, tight tolerances, quality design, in a high quality assurance factory targeting higher profit margins by a manufacturer that puts their name and money on the line with warranties and contracts.

Even worse if the random 3 dollar module you purchased is made with defective parts, factory seconds, ghost runs or straight counterfeits.